# Cloning script doesn't work in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot find the error in my code. This is supposed to be a simple clone and remove script. I am trying to convert it from a Jquery script, but no luck so far.

```js
document.querySelector(".wrapper").addEventListener("click", ".remove", function() {
  document.querySelector(".remove")
    .closest(".wrapper")
    .querySelector(".element")
    .not(":first")
    .last()
    .remove();
});
document.querySelector(".wrapper").addEventListener("click", ".clone", function() {
  document.querySelector(".clone")
    .closest(".wrapper")
    .querySelector(".element")
    .first()
    .clone()
    .appendTo(".results");
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}

.element {
  background: #eee;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.buttons {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="results"></div>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="clone">clone</button>
    <button class="remove">remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) does not work like that. If you want delegated event handlers, you have to check `event.target.closest(".clone")` or similar to get that.

Comment: What do you need to clone? And what will be removed if I press on "remove"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with you code, but the main error is that you are passing the wrong arguments to `addEventListener` whose syntax is `target.addEventListener(type, listener [, options]);` where `type` is the event type and `listener` is a callback function. The callback will be passed the event object intrinsically.

Since you are attaching the listener to the `wrapper` element, you need to evaluate the `event.target` when triggered to determine which button was actually clicked.

```
if (event.target.classList.contains('clone')) {...
```

You can then call the necessary function based on this evalution passing either the entire event object, or in the example below, just the element returned by `event.target`.

Next, while chaining will get you a long way, it is actually advantageous here to declare some variables to avoid multiple queries to the same element.

A few smaller things :

It isn't necessary to check for `first` as `querySelector` only returns the first element that matches.

Likewise, specifying `not(:first)` won't stop `querySelector` as it only returns the first.

In order to access the last element, you can simply get them all using `querySelectorAll` and retrieve the last element from the returned NodeList. (destructured to an array here)

```
[...allElements][allElements.length-1].remove();
```

```js
function clone(button) {
  const wrapper = button.closest(".wrapper");
  const cloneElement = wrapper.querySelector(".element").cloneNode(true);
  wrapper.querySelector(".results").appendChild(cloneElement);
}

function remove(button) {
  const allElements = button.closest(".wrapper").querySelectorAll(".element");
  if (allElements.length >1) [...allElements][allElements.length-1].remove();
}

document.querySelector(".wrapper").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('clone')) {
    clone(event.target);
  } else if (event.target.classList.contains('remove')) {
    remove(event.target);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}
.element {
  background: #eee;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.results .element {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
.buttons {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element">
  Element
  </div>
  <div class="results"></div>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="clone">clone</button>
    <button class="remove">remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```